# Decision tree with high cardinality attribute

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, cardinality

I want to learn a decision tree having a reasonable discrete target attribute with 5 possible different values.
However, there are discrete high cardinality input attributes (1000s of different possible string values) that I wonder if it makes sense to include them. Is there any policy what the maximum cardinality should be when including an attribute to train a decision tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no maximum cardinality, no. Of course, you could omit values that do not actually appear in the data.

You will have to use an RDF implementation that handles multi-label categorical features directly rather than converts them to a series of binary indicator features.

For a categorical feature with N values there are 2^N - 2 possible decision rules on the feature, which is too many to consider by a long way. The heuristic I have used is to compute the entropy of the target when you divide up the data by the N categorical feature values. Then order the values by entropy and evaluate the N-2 rules you get by considering prefixes of that list.

Comment: I know the OP didn't post any code in the question, but it would be great to see some pseudo code to represent the process you describe here... I am facing the same problem in a high dimensional dataset ( >3000 features), and am looking for a methodical way to set a threshold for max cardinality, so I know which features I can one-hot encode and which I need to discard or preprocess into coarser groupings

Comment: This sounds like a different setup (many features, vs a feature with many values), and different process (I didn't suggest removing features). Most implementations don't require you to one-hot encode your categorical features, so I wouldn't do that. The decision tree process kind of naturally does feature selection in that it tries features randomly and keeps useful decision rules. The resulting forest would only use a few of your features anyway, which means you can drop those features from the data.